# Stackdriver filter url contains

Tags: trace, stackdriver

I using stackdriver i have massive requests on resource. I need filter request for sub resource.
Example url:

`/api/1/resource/{id}/subresource`

How to filter only request for `/subresource` ?
This is possible using web version of trace?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution *(not the easiest)* would be to [install the Fluentd.org plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluent-plugin-google-cloud) and use wildcard as it is explain in this [link](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/in_tail#path)

```
path /api/1/resource/*
```